# Slot Machine Game In C - Printing Reels Issue

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I'm trying to create a small slot-machine game that has three reels and four possible symbols for each reel (bell, orange, cherry, and horse).

I started by generating a random value between 1-4 and now I'm trying to get the first reel to print out the text associated with the generated values.

Here is the code, I hope someone can help and point out why it doesn't work and how I can fix it. From the code below I was expecting the program to print out 3 different pieces of text that were associated with the generated numbers but instead "Cherry" prints out three times.

```
// Generates 3 different random values between 1-4 and stores them within the slotVal array.
int slotVal[3], counter;
srand(time(NULL));

for (counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++) {
     slotVal[counter] = rand() % 4 + 1;
}

// Checks generated values and prints associated text.
for (counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++) {
    if (slotVal[counter] = 1) {
       printf("Cherry");
    }

    else if (slotVal[counter] = 2) {
        printf("Bell");
    }

    else if (slotVal[counter] = 3) {
        printf("Orange");
    }
    else 
        printf("Horseshoe");
}
```

Comment: `==` is the comparison operator in C. You are using `=`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your if statements are wrong, you are assigning(=) not comparing(==):

```
// Checks generated values and prints associated text.
for (counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++) {
    if (slotVal[counter] == 1) {
       printf("Cherry");
    } else if (slotVal[counter] == 2) {
        printf("Bell");
    } else if (slotVal[counter] == 3) {
        printf("Orange");
    } else {
        printf("Horseshoe");
    }
}
```

If you do `if(something = 1)` the condition evaluated will be the `1` because the assignment operator returns the assigned variable. Since `1` evaluates to `true`, your first condition would be met and the other `else` blocks would be ignored.

---

Some useful tips to avoid this particular error are:

- Do `if(1 == variable)` instead of `if(variable == 1)`, because the first raises a compilation (if you only use one `=` sign) error and the second doesn't;
- Define a name for the comparison, for example: `#define EQUALS ==` which will allow you to do `if(variable EQUALS 10)`

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I spent over an hour confused about why it wouldn't work!

Answer (score 0):

When you program in C, always enable all compiler warnings that you can find. C is not a beginner-friendly language, and it provides you with plenty of ways to shoot yourself in the foot. Enabling compiler warnings protects against a few of these ways.

When you use GCC, at least enable the `-Wall -Wextra` warnings. They will warn you that in the `if` conditionals, you are using the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `==`.